# Receiving errors when trying to use stat_function in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

So my example data are:

```
x <- runif(1000, min = 0, max = 5)
y <- (2 / pi) * atan(x)
z <- floor(x)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
```

I draw boxplots of x, binned by z:

```
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = z)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
g
```

[image]

But the thing is, in my real-life data, I'm not completely sure that the y-values follow `(2 / pi) * atan(x)`. There's a random element there. So, how do I draw the function on top of my graph to see for myself? As per the ggplot2 documentation, I tried...

```
g + stat_function(fun = (2 / pi) * atan(x), colour = "red")
```

...but am receiving the error `Warning message:
Computation failed in 'stat_function()':
'what' must be a function or character string`.

Comment: your question is not clear for me. You think Y axes does not follow formula. So, are you concern about the `warnning`?

Comment: I want to draw `y = (2 / pi) * atan(x)` on top of my boxplot, and am receiving a warning when I try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is saying:

```
'what' must be a function or character string
```

so it is asking you simply define your function.

You need to define your function suuch as `func`

```
func<-function(x){  (2 / pi) * atan(x)}
```

and then call it in ggplot

```
library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = z)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
g+stat_function(fun = func, colour = "red")
```

Here is the result

[image]

Comment: @Darren i have enough knowledge, and i do not steal the other people answers.

Comment: I trust you, but it was a matter of priority. Our answer belong to identitical concept and I post it before you.

Comment: @Darren it sometimes happen. i upvote you because of your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

the parameter `fun` must be a function

```
g + stat_function(fun = function(x){(2 / pi) * atan(x)}, colour = "red")
```

Answer (score 3):

I could solve your problem by simply defining a new function and the pass it to as the argument of `stat_function`

Here it is

```
myfun <- function(x){(2 / pi) * atan(x)}
```

and then

```
g + stat_function(fun = myfun colour = "red")
```

would do it